# How to line up inner charta and outer chart in a Donut chart Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How can I line up inner charta and outer chart in a Donut chart Highcharts. Should a Donut chart have the outer data line up with inner chart?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean line-up, because donut uses two series, one for outer ring and one for inner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it should line up . Because Only if both the inner and outer values match , the do-nut chart will be pleasant to look (i.e) the color and the chart split will synchronize